# Show Date + Hour 0 count for dates that have no values for selected column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, temp-tables

My End goal is to get Min, Max, Average, and StDEV of record occurrences per hour, per category, per day of week. I am having trouble figuring out a good way to build a CTE or Temp table that has a record with count of records including 0 count per hour per category per day. My report table has a record for every day, but not for every hour of every day. I tried doing a recursive CTE, and ran into the 100 max recursions. I am running SQL 2012. With what I have I can get an accurate Max, and average, but not STDEV or MIN.

```
Declare @StartDate as DateTime
Set @StartDate = '20160101 00:00:00'
;
With Data as
(   
    Select 
        CAST(r.MyTimeStamp as Date) 'Record Date',
        DATENAME(WEEKDAY,r.MyTimeStamp) 'Day of Week',
        DATEPART(DW,r.MyTimeStamp) 'DayWeekNum',
        o.Category, 
        DATEPART(Hour,r.MyTimeStamp)'HourofDay'

    From Report r
    join [Order] o on r.ReportID = o.ReportID
    Where r.MyTimeStamp > @StartDate
),
DayCount1 as 
(   Select Distinct CAST(r.MyTimeStamp as date) 'The Date'
    , DATENAME(weekday,r.MyTimeStamp) 'Day of Week'
    From Report r
    Where r.MyTimeStamp > @StartDate
),
DayCount2 as
(
    Select d.[Day of Week], COUNT(*) 'WD COUNT'
    From DayCount1 d
    Group by d.[Day of Week]
),
Data2 as
(
Select d.[Record Date], 
    d.[Day of Week], 
    d.Category, 
    d.HourofDay
    , Count(*) 'Total Per Day', 
    t.[WD COUNT] 'Number of Days'

FROM Data d
Join DayCount2 d2 on d.[Day of Week] = d2.[Day of Week]
Group by d.[Record Date], d.DayWeekNum, d.[Day of Week],d2.[WD COUNT],d.Category, d.HourofDay
)

Select 
    d.[Day of Week]
    , d.Category
    , d.HourofDay
    , SUM(d.[Total Per Day]) 'Total Records During Hour'
    , MAX(d.[Total Per Day]) 'MAX per Hour'
    ,d.[Number of Days]
    , CAST(CAST(SUM(d.[Total Per Day]) as dec(8,2))/CAST(d.[Number of Days] as dec(8,2)) as dec(8,2)) 'Average'
From Data2 d
Where Category in ('A', 'B','C', 'D','E','F','G')
Group by d.[Day of Week], d.Category, d.HourofDay, d.[Number of Days]
Order by d.[Day of Week], d.Category, d.HourofDay
```

Sample Data

```
MyTimeStamp            ,    Category
2017-10-31 08:50:53.600,    A
2017-10-31 08:49:43.837,    B
2017-10-31 08:49:36.547,    A
2017-10-31 08:49:19.130,    B
2017-10-31 08:47:47.360,    C
2017-10-31 08:47:33.230,    A
2017-10-31 08:47:00.157,    B
2017-10-31 08:41:57.553,    B
2017-10-31 08:41:16.960,    A
2017-10-31 08:39:27.940,    A
```

Sample Output

```
Weekday Category    HourofDay   Rpt Cnt MIN MAX Average StDev
Friday      A       0           80      1   5   0.83    1.12
Friday      A       1           71      1   4   0.74    0.3
Friday      A       2           65      1   4   0.68    0.23
Friday      A       3           44      1   4   0.46    0.1
Friday      A       4           36      1   4   0.38    0.01
Friday      A       5           22      1   3   0.23    1.21
Friday      A       6           21      1   2   0.22    0.05
Friday      A       7           19      1   2   0.2     0.01
Friday      A       8           49      1   3   0.51    0.51
Friday      A       9           97      1   7   1.01    1.02
Friday      A       10          132     1   5   1.38    1.12
Friday      A       11          208     1   7   2.17    2
```

Comment: It's good that you showed where you got to so far however, if you can provide sample data and expected output then you can get a quicker response.

Comment: You need to use a tally or numbers table as the primary table of your query and then left join to your details. That way you always have 24 rows to start and can get rows with no details.

Comment: Sorry, The sample data, and output are not directly related. Just examples. of what it looks like.

Comment: @SeanLange I do not have a tally/ numbers table to pull from as a primary table. If there is a way to create one as a CTE or #TempTable I would love to learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep a tally table as a view on my system. This generates 10,000 rows with zero reads. This is actually faster than storing and reading 10,000 rows from a persistent table. I first learned about tally tables from Jeff Moden. He has an excellent article on the topic here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/ In fact the code to generate this tally table is from him. I just modified it to turn it into a view so I don't have to write this all the time.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Comment: So, how do I use that to generate table with Date and hours 1-24?

Comment: sorry, hours 0-23

Comment: Select N, Cast(DATEADD(DD, (N-1)/24, @StartDate) as Date)

This gives me 24 Day entries per day... Now I just need to add the hours...

Comment: Thanks Got it - Select N, Cast(DATEADD(HH, N-1, @StartDate) as Date) 'Day', DATEPART(HH, DATEADD(HH, N-1, @StartDate)) 'Hour'
From
cteTally